# How to format float in C without most significant digits?

Tags: c, format, numbers, double

I wanna output data look like this

```
input : 1999.99
output: 999.99
```

I wanna cut out the more significant digits.

I have been used C format like this

```
%.2f  ==> 10.44, 23.23, 5.67
```

And now i need to cut before decimal point.

Is any solution?

Comment: `I wanna output data look like this` `I wanna cut out the excess data.` - so you want your data to look like this or not? Which data are "excess data"? `i need to cut before decimal point.` - so you need your data to "look like this" or you need to cut before decimal point? What does it mean to "cut" a number "before decimal point"?

Comment: So you need the value modulo 1000.0?  Look for `modf()` from `<math.h>` (or is it `fmod()`?).

Comment: @KamilCuk i showed you that excess data is 1000.00. For example, If input data is 18734.34566, it would be 734.34

Comment: That's not formatting, that is changing the value altogether

Comment: output = fmod(input, 1000.0);

Comment: @robthebloke Ah, There is away. Thank you

Comment: TEom, the accepted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60069892/2410359) `format_3_2(18734.34566)`, does it give you 734.34 as specified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60069582/how-to-format-float-in-c-without-most-significant-digits#comment106239369_60069582) or 734.35?  Does the answer even compile for you?

Comment: "without most significant digits?" title is unclear.  A number like 1.25 without most significant digit would be 0.25 yet it appears you want 1.25. With input like 999.9950001, would you want 000.00 or what?  With -1999.99, do you want -999.99?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Truncating *extra* high order digits as requested can be obtained using the `fmod()` function:

```c
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void format_3_2(double input) {
    printf("%.2f", fmod(input, 1000.0));
}
```

input: `1999.99`
output: `999.99`

Note however that you should also round the input value **before** applying the `fmod()` function to avoid this: `printf("%.2f", fmod(1999.999, 1000.0));` -> `1000.00`. Use the `round` function for this:

```c
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void format_3_2(double input) {
    printf("%.2f", fmod(round(input * 100.0) / 100.0, 1000.0));
}
```

input: `1999.999`
output: `0.00`

Comment: Attempting to round before `fmod` is incorrect as it may add error when the product in `input * 100,.0` must be rounded to the floating-point format. Rounding with `round(input * 100.0) / 100.0` is generally incorrect for this reason. If OP desires results that would contain digits “000.00” when formatted to two digits after the decimal point to be displayed thusly (or as “0.00” or similar) and desires numbers that would not contain those digits not to be displayed thusly, then a more sophisticated rounding method must be used…

Comment: Since the numerical techniques for perform such rounding are complicated, the simplest approach for many programmers is simply to format the number using `sprintf` and then perform whatever character manipulations on the string to accomplish any effects they desire.

Comment: `#include <math.h> void format_3_2(double input) {
    printf("%.2f", fmod(round(input * 100.0)) / 100.0, 1000.0));
}` --> "error: too few arguments to function 'fmod'", "error: expected ';' before ')' token", "error: expected statement before ')' token".  Needs review.